# ViSEAGO tutorial: visualising topGO object

Tags: r, data-visualization, ontology, rna-seq

Earlier, I had [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639543/error-when-i-load-my-own-data-using-viseago-create-topgo) and was able to load in my data successfully and create a topGO object after some help. I'm trying to visualise GO terms that are significantly associated with the list of differentially expressed genes that I have from mouse RNA-seq data.

Now, I'd want to raise a concern about [ViSEAGO's tutorial](https://rdrr.io/bioc/ViSEAGO/f/vignettes/ViSEAGO.Rmd). The tutorial initially specifies loading two files: 'selection.txt' and 'background.txt'. The origin of these files is not clearly stated. However, after a lot of digging into topGO's documentation, I was able to find the datatypes for each of the files. But, even after following these, I have a problem running the following code. Does anyone have any insights to share?

WORKING CODE:

```
mysampleGOdata <- new("topGOdata",
                      description = "my Simple session",
                      ontology = "BP",
                      allGenes = geneList_new,
                      nodeSize = 1,
                      annot = annFUN.org,
                      mapping="org.Mm.eg.db", 
                      ID = "SYMBOL")

resultFisher <- runTest(mysampleGOdata, algorithm = "classic", statistic = "fisher")

head(GenTable(mysampleGOdata,fisher=resultFisher),20)

myNewBP<-GenTable(mysampleGOdata,fisher=resultFisher)
```

PROBLEMS:

```
> head(myNewBP,2)
       GO.ID                      Term Annotated Significant Expected  fisher
1 GO:0006006 glucose metabolic process       194          12     0.19 1.0e-19
2 GO:0019318  hexose metabolic process       223          12     0.22 5.7e-19

> ###################
> # merge results
> myBP_sResults<-ViSEAGO::merge_enrich_terms(
+   Input=list(
+     condition=c("mysampleGOdata","resultFisher")
+   )
+ )
Error in setnames(x, value) : 
  Can't assign 3 names to a 2 column data.table
> myNewBP<-GenTable(mysampleGOdata,fisher=resultFisher)
> ###################
> # display the merged table
> ViSEAGO::show_table(myNewBP)
Error in ViSEAGO::show_table(myNewBP) : 
  object must be enrich_GO_terms, GO_SS, or GO_clusters class objects
```

According to the tutorial, the printed table contains for each enriched GO terms, additional columns including the list of significant genes and frequency (ratio of the number of significant genes to the number of background genes) evaluated by comparison. I think I have that, but it's definitely not working.

Can someone see why? I'm not very clear on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sruthi, did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same problem re: can't assign 3 names to a 2 column data.table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to circumvent an error you made at the beginning. You receive the error due to the fact that you did not use the wrapper function from the ViSEAGO package. As you stated [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639543/error-when-i-load-my-own-data-using-viseago-create-topgo), you had initial problems formatting your data.

Here are some tips:

- The "selection" file is a character vector with your DEGs names or IDs. I recommend using EntrezID's.
- The "Background" file is a character vector with known genes. I recommend using EntrezID's as well. You can easily generate this character vector with:
  `background=keys(org.Hs.eg.db, keytype ='ENTREZID')`.
- With these two files, you can easily proceed to the next steps of the package as described in the [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ViSEAGO/inst/doc/ViSEAGO.html).

```
# connect to EntrezGene
EntrezGene<-ViSEAGO::EntrezGene2GO()

# load GO annotations from EntrezGene
# with the add of GO annotations from orthologs genes (see above)
#id = "9606" = homo sapiens
myGENE2GO<-ViSEAGO::annotate(id="9606", EntrezGene)

BP<-ViSEAGO::create_topGOdata(
  geneSel = selection, #your DEG vector
  allGenes = background, #your created background vector
  gene2GO=myGENE2GO, 
  ont="BP",
  nodeSize=5
)

classic<-topGO::runTest(
  BP,
  algorithm ="classic",
  statistic = "fisher"
)

# merge results
BP_sResults<-ViSEAGO::merge_enrich_terms(
  Input=list(
    condition=c("BP","classic")
  )
)
```

You should get a merged list of your enriched GO terms with the corresponding statistical tests you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem recently, it was very frustrating. In my case the whole issue seemed to be related to the package version I was using.

I used conda to install ViSEAGO. Nevertheless, R's version in my conda environment was a bit old (i.e. 3.6.1 to be specific). Therefore, when installing ViSEAGO with conda, the version 1.0.0 of the package was installed. Please note that the most recent version of ViSEAGO is 1.4.0.

Therefore, I created a conda environment with R version 4.0.3, and repeated the procedure to install ViSEAGO by using conda. When doing this, ViSEAGO's 1.4.0 version was installed, and everything went fine.

I've tried to backtrack the error, and only find one thing: in the older ViSEAGO version, the function Custom2GO loaded tables with 4 columns; in the most recent version it admits 5 columns (the new one being 'gene_symbol'). I think this disagreement might be part of the issue, as the source code of the function merge_enrich_terms seems to deal with the columns 'gene_id' and 'gene_symbol' at some point, but I'm not sure.

Hope you find my comment helpful!

Cheers,
Mauricio